# browser downloading twice the images when lazy loading with js

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, safari, lazy-loading

I am developing a website and I have a problem with lazy loading images.

It was taking too much time to load the images so I checked the Browser Network Tab and I saw that Safari was loading multiple times the same image, slowing down the loading of the other media.

I reproduced the code to make as simple as possible and when I lazy load images the browser load them twice.

```
<style type="text/css">
[data-src]{
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all .4s ease;
}
[data-src].vis{
  opacity: 1;
}
</style>

<img data-src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/045b1f/ffff11" src="dot.png">
<img data-src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/045b44/ffff22" src="dot.png">
<img data-src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/045b77/ffff33" src="dot.png">
<img data-src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/045b00/ffff44" src="dot.png">

<script type="text/javascript">

  function lazy(){
    $('[data-src]').each(function(){
      var $img = $(this);
      var src = $img.attr('data-src');
      var img = new Image();
      img.src = src;
      $(img).on('load', function(){
        console.log('loaded',src);
        $img.attr('src',this.src);
        $img.addClass('vis');
      });
    });  
  }

  jQuery(function($){

    setTimeout(function(){
      lazy();
    },3000)

  });
</script>
```

I also made a CodePen https://codepen.io/nbl7/pen/GaoZXW

On my website this happen only on Safari and it loads the same image even 10 times. Probably because I call the lazy load function different times.

On the code I provided it happens also on Chrome.

Should the browser know already which image has been loaded and cache them without making new requests?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a code that doesn't load the images twice:

```js
function lazy() {
  $('[data-src]').each(function() {
    var img = this;
    var src = $(img).attr('data-src');
    $(img).attr('src', src);
    $(img).on('load', function() {
      console.log('loaded', src);
      $(img).addClass('vis');
    });
  });
}

jQuery(function($) {
  // lazy();
  setTimeout(function() {
    lazy();
  }, 3000)

});
```

```css
[data-src] {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all .4s ease;
}

[data-src].vis {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<img data-src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/045b1f/ffff11" src="">
<img data-src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/045b44/ffff22" src="">
<img data-src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/045b77/ffff33" src="">
<img data-src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/045b00/ffff44" src="">
```

You set the **img src** twice in your loop, and that means that it loads twice:

- on this line: **img.src = src;** (line 6)
- then on this line: **$img.attr('src',this.src);** (line 9)